# Php mail: how to send html?

Tags: php, html, email, message, sendmail

The code below is sending an email correctly but for the body. I need to show html in the body of the message and I cannot make it. The examples in the web won't send the email :(

How can I fix my code to send the email with the html in the body?

Thanks a ton!

```
<?php

$to = 'mymail@mail.com';

$subject = 'I need to show html'; 

$from ='example@example.com'; 

$body = '<p style=color:red;>This text should be red</p>';

ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);

$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

  echo("<p>Sent</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Error...</p>");
 }

?>
```

Comment: +1 for question I had similarly question but this thread answers it ( from various angles )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this header for the mail:

```
 $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
```

and for the content/body:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
... ... ...
```

it's important to use inline css commands and recommanded to use tables for the interface.

**...**

In your Mail-Body you than have to put [HTML code with head and body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html)

Comment: Thanks helle, but error in the headers and no html in the body :(

Comment: change your line to this as well. and close all tags you have opened. and use `<body>` tag. 
`$headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\nReply-To: " . $from . "";`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it:  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
sends the email with the text in read what is great. But in the from field is shown www-data .. how can I fix that? Once it is done it will be over. Thanks a lot

Comment: @helle you mean its better to use tables than divs for layout?

Comment: @Sam in the case of mails: yes.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the headers of the incoming mail? It says

```
Reply-To: example@example.comContent-type: text/html
```

Simply add another `\r\n` here:

```
Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend rather than messing around with doing this yourself you use one of the many free classes available all over the web to do it.

I would recommend: [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I found this works well!

[Source](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php)

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test HTML email'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\""; 
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

Comment: Found it too but not sending in my case, why?

Comment: This relied upon the mail command. This command is present is most *NIX systems.

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer: Don't do it. HTML emails are evil and annoying. At least if there's no PROPER plaintext version included. Proper = same information like in the HTML version, not just a stupid comment about getting another email client or a link to the html version if it's available on the web.

If you really need it: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime

Comment: They can be annoying if being misused. Though, if used carefully, they are quite good. In my opinion, best practice is to send both plain/text and plain/html bodies, so user can chose which one he wants to see.