# Modification to mail() to include a variable in the message

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php mail: how to send html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897215/php-mail-how-to-send-html)

I want to use the Mail() function in PHP but I am having some difficulties to include a link and a variable in the messagge.

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

How can I send the message below?

```
Please click <a href="http://domain.com/verify.php?token=$token">here</a> to veify.
```

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Example #4 Sending HTML email

Comment: @Dagon he's having a problem with escaping, that's all.

Comment: @AhmedJolani more than that, he's adding html to the email with out using the appropriate headers

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create an HTML email which is pretty much a lot of work if you want to do it from scratch and so many things can actually go wrong.

Instead of doing it by hand use **PHPMailer** (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) along with its `MsgHTML()` method to add HTML content to the message body.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "http://domain.com/verify.php?token=$token";
$message = "Please click <a href=\"{$var}\">here</a> to veify.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$message .="Please click <a href=\"http://domain.com/verify.php?token=\"{$token}\">here</a> to veify.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Comment: SO's syntax highlighter is great for catching stupid bugs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oops! :) Fixed

Comment: html mail should set the Content-type header header.

Comment: @Dagon - Very true. Edits made above.