# How to customize the way an email looks sent from a php mail() script

Tags: php, html, contact-form

So I can't seem to word the question right - but I would like to know how would you go about changing the way this

```
$Body = "";
$Body .=   "Name: ";  
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "City: ";
$Body .= $City;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
```

looks when it reaches my e-mail. When I receive the e-mail (using it as a contact form), I get this ->

```
Name: lloan
City: SomeCity
Email: some@email.com
Message: Testing
```

I tried `<strong> $Body .=   "Name: ";</strong>` and that didn't work - I also tried it as `$Body .=   "<strong> Name: </strong>";` and again, nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I really want to learn how to do this - I've googled it a couple of times, but I think it's the way I'm wording my question that's not helping me.

EDIT: So I'm able to do this now - `$Body .=   "<strong>Name: </strong>";` using the suggestions below of adding the headers and then adding that to the mail() function - however, how do I go about using it on a bigger scale? For example - What if I want to have a colored background or what not - Am I also able to use CSS in this kind of situation? The other questions on SO do not answer this in it's entirety.

Comment: If you want to sent HTML email, you have to put `Content-type: text/html` in the header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mail: how to send html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897215/php-mail-how-to-send-html)

Comment: http://fil.ya1.ru/PHP_5_in_Practice/index.htm#page=0768667437/ch16lev1sec1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
$to = 'yourmailtarget@example.com';

$subject = 'Your email subject';

$headers = "From: abc@abc.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@abc.com \r\n";
$headers .= "CC: abc@abc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = 'Put your html message here<br>';
$message .= "<b>HTML feature is now enabled</b><br>";
$message .= "<table border="1"><tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr></table>";
$message .= "For the styling, you can use inline styling:<Br>";
$message .= "<span style='color:#FF0000;'>This is red color</span>";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$parameters);
```

The most important part to answer your question is this line:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

That tells the system to produce the email using the HTML format.

Hope this helps

Comment: How exactly could I use HTML after doing the above (which works btw) so that I could alter stuff like background-color and so on - At the moment, it only lets me use the `<strong>` tag :(!

Comment: @Alas: For the styling, you can use inline styling. I have updated my sample above with inline styling adding red color to one of the line

Comment: @RyonnSan why do you use `ISO-8859-1` and not `utf-8`?

Comment: @vladkras: either way should be fine, but since majority of people is using utf-8, I update my code to using utf-8

Answer (score 1):

In the mail function add a parameter headers like this :

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

and call the mail function like this :

mail($to, $subject, $Body, $headers)

If you would like to format your message (the content of variable $Body), you are free to use as much HTML as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send HTML email you also need to send a text-only version as not all mail clients support HTML, and some mail systems specifically strip HTML versions.

This means you need a `Content-type:multipart` header, and multiple sections with their own headers, each delimited by a specific boundary. The actual format is quote complex, so use a library like [swiftmail](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)