# How can i put some design on my message that i am going to send to email?

Tags: php

I've tried this code but i didn't work

Code in index.php

```
<form action='send.php' method='post'>
    Sender: <input type='text' name='sender'> </ br>
    Message: textarea name='message'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send' />
</form>
```

Code in send.php

```
$to = "my_email@yahoo.com";

$sender = $_POST['sender'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$design_message = "<div style='background-color: red'>" . $message . "</div>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 mail($to, "Test", $design_message, "From: " . $sender);

}
```

The message will be send to my email but it doesn't have any design

Comment: dont you know how to design in HTML??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mail: how to send html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897215/php-mail-how-to-send-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send an email that contains `HTML` content you have to add the following headers:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

You can send them here

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                              ^
```

[Source](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)