# How to create html mail body in php?

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to write a code for my mail body. i have a php file in called mailfunction.php.

In that file i have created a variable which has my html code as follow

```
 $message_body ="<html><body>"
."<table class='tg' style='border-style: dotted;'>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Civilité</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($titre) . "</td></tr>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Prénom</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($prenom) . "</td></tr>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Nom</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($nom) . "</td></tr>"
          . "</table></body></html>";
```

But unfortunatly my mail received mail didn't encode the htlm tags. I have received some text contained html tags which are not encoded as follow

```
<table class="tg" style="border-style: dotted;">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-3zav">Civilité</th>
    <th class="tg-3zav">M</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-3zav">Nom</td>
    <td class="tg-3zav">Frank</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-3zav">Prénom</td>
    <td class="tg-3zav">Betrix</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any idea to write this html code in the php file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mail: how to send html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897215/php-mail-how-to-send-html)

Comment: You have to declare that its an HTML e-mail. See the link @caCtus posted above to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the headers in mail function

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message ="<html><body>"
."<table class='tg' style='border-style: dotted;'>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Civilité</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($titre) . "</td></tr>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Prénom</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($prenom) . "</td></tr>"
          ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Nom</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($nom) . "</td></tr>"
          . "</table></body></html>";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Why set the headers like that? Why not just have `headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";` Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Infact i have i have changed my content-type to 'text/html'

Comment: Here is my corrected full code $headers .= 'From: ADMIN SERVER' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc-cc@admin-server.org' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

 $message_body ="<html><body>"
    ."<style type='text/css'>"
    ."tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}"
    ."</style>"
    ."<table class='tg' style='border-style: dotted;'>"
    ."</table></body></html>";

Comment: Cool you must add the header type on mail  :) thanks for upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Here I post my the corrected source code

```
$headers .= 'From: ADMIN SERVER' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc-cc@admin-server.org' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$message_body ="<html><body>"
                ."<style type='text/css'>"
                ."tg {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}"
                ."</style>"
                ."<table class='tg' style='border-style: dotted;'>"
                ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Civilité :</td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($titre) . "</td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Prénom : </td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($prenom) . "</td></tr>"
                ."<tr><td class='tg-3zav'>Nom : </td><td class='tg-3zav'>" . strip_tags($nom) . "</td></tr>"
                ."</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Instead of posting this you should accept the answer above that helped you (click on the green tick)

Comment: Sometime i don't have that privillage. that's why i have added the corrected version was given by you!

Comment: Every user has the privilege  to accept an answer. It's upvoting you can't do until you get a few rep points.